# How to submit sitemap when your website has partial https? - Error: "Not in Domain"

Tags: google-search-console, https, ecommerce, robots.txt

My website is an eCommerce that is set up to do HTTP for the item browsing portion, but HTTPS for things like shopping cart, contact us, etc.. (anything that has forms on it).

I've submitted my website a long time ago to Google webmaster tools as `http://example.com`.  I also submitted a sitemap with about 40 links - 8 of them are HTTPS.

I've noticed that for the longest time, Google webmaster tools was reporting that 32 out of the 40 links have been crawled.  I tested all the links against my robots.txt and realized that my robots text was blocking the HTTPS links.  Google says those links are "Not In Domain".

Is there a way I'm supposed to get around this so that I can have a hybrid-ssl site?  I understand the concept that one site is mywebsite.com:80 and the other is mywebsite.com:443, but I'd like to avoid submitting and maintaining 2 separate websites on Google webmaster tools.

Comment: Ralph, Were you able to figure this issue out? I am having the same situation as my homepage is under SSL and it is not being tracked or indexed on my current http webmaster account (although it has been indexed by google in search). Cheers,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

You could submit 2 sitemaps (one for http and one for https) as well. But I think the problem is that the https domain is not verified. [Here is some background information](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75712) from Google on what works and what not. Eric is right that you need only one sitemap.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to have two websites in webmaster tools - it should handle http/https on the same site just fine.

Just removing those urls from your robots.txt file should solve the problem.